# How to change or remove the copyright text in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, copyright

How to modify the copyright text on Magento website?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it from

```
Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Design (left menu) -> Footer ->  Copyright
```

Comment: Don't forget to invalidate any caches (full page or 3rd Party) in use - the footer is usually cached as a static HTML block instead of being rendered dynamically in real-time.  If you're using compilation (which I'd advise against) you may also need to recompile as well.

Answer (score 0):

After you log in go to admin panel, go to Simply,

```
Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Design (left menu) -> Footer ->  Copyright
```